# Adding MergedDictionaries field from C# code

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

XAML variant:

```
<Application.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="needed line" />
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

How can I add this using code? (I'm trying not to use xaml at all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In somewhere in App.xaml.cs (e.g. constructor)

```cs
var src1 = new ResourceDictionary { Source = new Uri("Dictionary1.xaml", UriKind.Relative) };
this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(src1);
```

---

Edit: Or you mean you wanna build the resource to merge without XAML?

If so, do like this

```cs
//build some resources
var btnStyle = new Style(typeof(Button));
btnStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.Red));

var src1 = new ResourceDictionary();
src1.Add("btnStyleKey", btnStyle);

this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(src1);
```

Comment: FluentWPF lib tells in instructions to add   <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/FluentWPF;component/Styles/Controls.xaml" />   in ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries but the example is for xaml and I create the project without using xaml at all. It needs to apply xaml file with styled controls. First variant returns exit code -532 462 766, the second I don't know how to apply in my case.

Comment: Why don't you do this instead.

```
var fw = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/FluentWPF;component/Styles/Controls.xaml") };
this.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(fw);
```